# Using Net::Telnet::Cisco and Net::Ping to skip unreachable hosts

Tags: perl

I am writing a script that goes through a few hundred Juniper routers and runs some commands to display using Net::Telnet::Cisco; however, some of the routers in the list are unreachable stopping the script through a Timeout.

Is there a way to skip the unreachable devices?  Maybe using the Net::Ping mod?

The message I recieve:

```
[user@server LSP]$ perl lsp_down_script.pl 
problem connecting to "<router-name>", port 23: Connection timed out at lsp_down_script.pl line 21
<table border=1><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr></tr><tr>[user@server LSP]$
```

Comment: @cespinoza - how would I make it so that when it times out, it goes to the next box?

Comment: Parallel:ForkManager is the simple way to solve this problem

Comment: @cespinoza, this is a service provider mpls backbone, it's rather unlikely any firewalls are blocking access... OP there is no sane reason for you to use telnet to internet backbone routers... ssh has been available for years now

Comment: Yes I know that.....   We will be switching to ssh, but in the meantime, there are no issues using telnet.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Errmode for the `Net::Telnet` base of `Net::Telnet::Cisco` you can have the timeout return (code from one of my Cisco scripts):

```
$telnet = new Net::Telnet::Cisco(Timeout => 5, Errmode => 'return');
foreach my $hostid (@listofhosts) {
    if (!$telnet->open($hostid)) {
        print "\tError on telnet to $hostid: ", $telnet->errmsg(), "\n";
        next;
    }

    # work with device: $telnet->login(), etc
}
```

Note: My version of Net::Telnet::Cisco has a few bug fixes:

1. The warnings initialization line 66 has an incorrect `/` on the end
2. The `warnings` sub is missing (I add it at line 687):

   ```
   sub warnings {
       my ($self, $arg) = @_;
       my $stream = $ {*self}{net_telnet_cisco};
       $stream->{warnings} = $arg if defined $arg;
       return $stream->{warnings};
   }
   ```
3. The RE on line 740 (original) or 746 (after `warnings` is added) assigning `my ($delim, $re)` is missing s on the end